# How to prevent integer value from getting truncated

Tags: java

```
String s = "128166947252913248";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##########################.########");
Double oldTime1 = new Double(s); 
Double oldTime2 = new Double("128166947252913249"); 
Double oldTime3 = new Double("128166947252913247");
Double newTime = new Double("116444736000000000");
System.out.println(newTime.longValue());
System.out.println(df.format(oldTime1));
System.out.println(oldTime1-newTime);
System.out.println(df.format(oldTime1-newTime));
System.out.println(df.format(oldTime3-newTime));
```

Output is :

```
116444736000000000
128166947252913248
1.1722211252913248E16
11722211252913248
11722211252913248
```

This is the code I am working on. I am unable to stop double variable getting truncated at the last variable. Please help me to get a value without being truncated.

Comment: Do you know about `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`? They can be used to save larger numbers, or larger amounts of precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
String s = "128166947252913248";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(
        "##########################.########");
BigDecimal oldTime1 = new BigDecimal(s);
BigDecimal oldTime2 = new BigDecimal("128166947252913249");
BigDecimal oldTime3 = new BigDecimal("128166947252913247");
BigDecimal newTime = new BigDecimal("116444736000000000");
System.out.println(newTime.longValue());
System.out.println(df.format(oldTime1));
System.out.println(oldTime1.subtract(newTime));
System.out.println(df.format(oldTime1.subtract(newTime)));
System.out.println(df.format(oldTime3.subtract(newTime)));
```

Answer (score 4):

`Double` does not have enough precision for eighteen decimal digits: [64-bit IEEE-754 numbers have at most 17 decimal digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). You should use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for unlimited precision.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I just changed the program with big decimal and it is working as expected.